# Strange Custom Background Color on UIPickerView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uipickerview

I'm getting strange colors when assigning a custom UIColor to the background of UIPickerViews. I have created a color for textViews and pickerViews as follows:

```
let myTextViewBackgroundColor = UIColor(red: 192.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.35)
```

And I assign it as:

```
myTextView.backgroundColor = myTextViewBackgroundColor
keywordPicker.backgroundColor = myTextViewBackgroundColor
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]
As you can see, the color of the textViews and the color of the picker are different. The difference seems more pronounced on a device than in this snapshot, but the custom color looks muddy, almost like it is mixed with a default gray background.

If I comment out the pickerView color item above, I get a gray color background:
[image]
If I choose a standard UIColor, it appears to work correctly. UIColor.yellowColor in this instance. If I choose white, that looks good, too.
[image]
I create the pickerView in code and assign it to a textField which has no background color assigned.

```
var keywordPicker : UIPickerView?

keywordPicker = UIPickerView()
keywordPicker?.delegate = self
keywordPicker?.dataSource = self

keywordsForItemTextField.inputView = keywordPicker
keywordPicker.backgroundColor = myTextViewBackgroundColor
```

And for what it's worth, I have a date picker that I created as a modal screen with it's own view controller. In that case, the picker is created on the storyboard. I still assign my background color with code and that picker shows the correct color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tkanzakic's answer finally allowed me to change the background color of UIDatePicker.

Here's the Swift 4 version:

```
class CustomDatePicker: UIDatePicker {

    var customBackgroundColor = UIColor.black

    override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?) {
        super.willMove(toWindow: newWindow)

        if newWindow != nil {
            inputView?.backgroundColor = customBackgroundColor
        }
    }
}
```

Change the customBackgroundColor property to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a result of the UIPickerView having that silvery-grey filter over it always (notice how it's grey when you have it set to white?)

Comment: When I set it to white it looks just like the rest of the background - it doesn't look gray. And again, I separately created a date picker from a storyboard and my custom color looks exactly as I expect. (the above gray photo is the situation when I do not specify ANY background color).

Comment: How do you disable that? The silvery-grey filter

Answer (score 0):

This response does not expose the cause of the issue, but I've included my resolution in case it will help others. I created a label for the selected row display and set the background color of the label. This label color is true to the custom settings.

I give a nod to Making App Pie and article https://makeapppie.com/2014/10/21/swift-swift-formatting-a-uipickerview/
which was the inspiration. Set the background to white:

```
    keywordPicker?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Also I added a border so the picker looks like the textViews I created:

```
    keywordPicker?.layer.borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 212.0/255.0, green: 212.0/255.0, blue: 212.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    keywordPicker?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    keywordPicker?.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
    keywordPicker?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Setup the label:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    var titleData : String = String()

    if pickerView == keywordPicker {
        titleData = crsuKeywordPickerList![row]
    }
    pickerLabel.text = titleData

    pickerLabel.backgroundColor = myPickerBackgroundColor
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    return pickerLabel

}//pickerView:viewForRow:...

The result:
```

[image]

```
As a second option as discussed above, if you instantiate the picker on the storyboard this problem does not appear.
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case we have a wrapper around the `UIPickerView` to build a custom date picker. After setting the appearance proxy of the `UITextField` class to use dark mode for the `inputView` we have the same glitch if the first `textField` that becomes active is one with the custom picker as `inputView`, but if the user interact before with a textField with the *normal keyboard* as `inputView` the glitch do not appear.

In our particular case adding this hack to the wrapper view fix the issue:

```
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow
{
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];

    if (newWindow) {
        self.pickerView.backgroundColor = self.colorPalette.inputViewBackgroundColor;
    }
}
```

We also tried setting the color in the `willMoveToSuperview:` method but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

write your background color change code inside:-

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { 

    if textField == self.tourtextfieldtextField {
        //for background color of picker
        datePickerView.backgroundColor = .red
        //text color of picker
        datePickerView.setValue( colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.5529411765, blue: 0.537254902, alpha: 1), forKeyPath: "textColor")
        datePickerView.setValue(0.8, forKeyPath: "alpha")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**swift 4.2 / xcode 10:**

The background color need to be set in the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
keywordPicker.backgroundColor = myTextViewBackgroundColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `silvery-grey` overlay on the UIPickerView you can add the following.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    for subview in pickerView.subviews {
        subview.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```