# How to change background color of UIPickerView in Cordova?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova, uipickerview

I am working on a Cordova App. which has a  in index.html.
In the iOS app the  is translated to a UIPickerView.

Here is what select tag looks like in index.html

```
  <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
                Lightsaber
            </div>
            <select>
                <option>Blue</option>
                <option selected>Green</option>
                <option>Red</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
```

So when user taps the  it opens a UIPickerView which looks like this.

I want to change the background color (say Green) of the UIPickerView. Is there a way to override the property in native Swift/Objective-C?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that from Xcode. You'd have to make a plugin to change the background color programmatically.

Comment: I am confused. Usually, in all Cordova Plugins, we write code that calls native Swift/Objective-C code. So whether we are writing a plugin or not we will have to modify native code in one way or another.  Please tell me if my understanding of Cordova Plugins is incorrect.

Comment: Yes you will have to write native code, though I don't see what this has to do with xcode.

Comment: My bad. When I say Xcode I meant Swift/Objective-C. I should rephrase the question. Can you tell me how to modify Swift/Objective-C code to achieve that?

Comment: It maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963049/strange-custom-background-color-on-uipickerview-swift you'd have to integrate this into a plugin.